# Model values returned as null on form post

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, post

I read various posts related to same problem but can't seem to find a solution. I have a MVC 4 application where I specify a form

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveFirstAmountPayable", "Policy", FormMethod.Post, 
       new Dictionary<string, object> { { "name", "frmPolicyFirstAmountPayable" }, 
                                        { "id", "frmPolicyFirstAmountPayable" } }))
{
     @Html.Kendo().HtmlHelper.TextBoxFor(m => 
                    m.FirstAmountPayable.FirstAmountPayableDescription, 
                    new Dictionary<string, object> { { "id", "txtDescription" }})

     // Some other inputs bounded to the model.
}
```

I have a button

```
<button class="btn grey" type="button" id="btnSave" name="btnSave">Save</button>
```

and some JQuery code that will do some validation and then submit the form with

```
$(formId).submit();
```

I have a breakpoint in my controller and all values within the model that is passed is null. Any ideas why this would happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the problem hope this helps someone in the future,

I added the following code snippet to my controller to see if I found any ModelState errors

```
 foreach (var modelState in ViewData.ModelState.Values)
 {
     foreach (var error in modelState.Errors)
     {
        // Do something with the error.
     }
 }
```

and found that the model binding failed because of a string conversion it could not perform. This made me look closer at the input fields in my form and I found the following

```
@Html.Kendo().HtmlHelper.RadioButtonFor(m => m.FirstAmountPayable, 
              "Condition", new { @class = "type-radio", @id = "chkCondition" })
```

***m => m.FirstAmountPayable*** is my model and can obviously not be bound to a radio button. Once I fixed this everything worked as expected.